# how to pass string variable of JavaScript to html form input,

Tags: javascript, html, arrays

Like if I have element of array `name[1]='ahmad'` and I want it to be posted in html form.

I used

```
document.getElementById('n').value=name[1];
```

but it's not posting.

Form has:

```
<input type="text" id="n" readonly="true">
```

i want to fill array by user and show these values in input readonly boxes on web page.
full code is:

```
<!dochtml html>
<title>Arrays of Js</title><!--different methods of using declaring arrays-->
<head>
<h3>Arrays usage by AFRN</h3>
    <script>
    alert('hey');
    var names=[];
    //var n = prompt('enter name');
        for(var i=0; i<=4; i++){
            names[i]=prompt('enter name: ');
        }
    /*var ids=['r1','r2','r3','r4','r5']
        for(var i=0; i<=4; i++){
            document.getElementById(ids).value=name[i];
        }*/
    document.getElementById("r1").value=names[0];
    document.getElementById("r2").value=names[1];
    document.getElementById("r3").value=names[2];
    document.getElementById("r4").value=names[3];
    document.getElementById("r5").value=names[4];
    </script>
        <noscript>JS not supported</noscript>
</head>
<body bgcolor="yellow">
    <form name="arryForm">
        <input type="text" id='r1' name="a1" readonly="true"> 
        <input type="text" id='r2' name="a2" readonly="true"> 
        <input type="text" id='r3' name="a3" readonly="true"> 
        <input type="text" id='r4' name="a4" readonly="true"> 
        <input type="text" id='r5' name="a5" readonly="true"> 
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Please click `<>` and post a [mcve] - you likely try to update the field before it exists

Comment: the limited code you described works fine https://jsfiddle.net/x1eo8qj8/ ... note: having a var called `name` in the global scope (not sure it is as you've provided a single line of code) can be troublesome

Comment: This doesn’t post the form just by setting the value .. you need to also call the submit method on the form element

Comment: better if you can provide a sample working snippet

Comment: Might not be relevant but is your script running before the page is loaded? Either load scripts after the body loads or use a onload event

Comment: i've uploaded the whole code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you move your `<script>` tag with its contents to the bottom just before the closing `</body>` tag and it will work.

Comment: you needed to place your script before the closing body so that the elements inside of body would be loaded first; otherwise your script was firing beforehand and had no elements to access. take a peak here, too: https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_whereto.asp

Answer (score 0):

You can try this code !
Place your javascript code below the **input** tag in body and you cannot use the variable name 'name' , I think this is not allowed in javascript because I am also facing problem with the varaible name 'name' so I am using '_name' .

```js
var _name = ["usman","ahmed"];
document.getElementById("n").value = _name[1];
```

```html
<input type="text"  id="n" readonly="true"/>
```